# What sort of metadata should I include on my site for rich previews in iMessage?

Tags: meta-tags, rich-snippets, ios

As you can see in this screenshot taken from Apple’s [iOS 10 preview page](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios10-preview/), the Messages app in iOS 10 will offer inline previews of URLs that are sent in conversations:

[image: Screenshot of Messages in iOS 10, showing a link that has automatically been annotated with the webpage’s title and a photo]

How can I ensure that my site appears properly in this context? Is there any official documentation from Apple about the specific metadata they’re using to generate these previews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's at least using [Open Graph](http://ogp.me) and [Twitter Card](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/).

### Demos

**[Open Graph](https://www.j-26.com/test/facebook.html)**

*Markup:*

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.j-26.com/assets/facebook.jpg"/>
```

*Preview:*

[image]

---

**[Twitter Card](https://www.j-26.com/test/twitter.html)**

*Markup:*

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.j-26.com/assets/twitter.jpg"/>
```

[image]

---

### Notable findings

I tested [this page](https://www.j-26.com/test/) using Twitter Card and Open graph and iOS seemed to prefer Open Graph. On the page, the Twitter Card markup is placed before the Open Graph markup *and* the image used in Twitter Card is **smaller** than the one used in Open Graph.